# Using ui bootstrap with angular 1.5 es6 - component is not working , go binding params undefined

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular1.6

I am using angular 1.6 webpack  es6 .

1 imported bootstrap as following (how can I import only the moda? )  in app.js module

```
import uiBootstrap from 'angular-ui-bootstrap';
```

2- call to uibmodal open from service :

```
$uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    backdrop:'static',
    component: 'testModal',
    windowClass: "class",
    windowTopClass: "class2",
    resolve: {
        data: function(){
           return data;
        }
    }})
```

3- created a component like :

```
class TestModalController{
    constructor(){
        console.log(this.resolve) . // got undefined
        console.log(this.close) // got undefined
        console.log(this.dismiss) // got undefined
    }

    $onInit(){
// not working also if i tryinh to get the binding here

    }
}



const TestModalComponent = {
    binding:{
        resolve: '<',
        close: '&',
        dismiss: '&'
    },
    template: TestModalTemplate,
    controller: TestModalController
};

export default TestModalComponent;
```

If I open the HTML I see the following component was generated:

```
<test-modal resolve="$resolve" modal-instance="$uibModalInstance"
            close="$close($value)" dismiss="$dismiss($value)"
            class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"> ......</test-modal>
```

The problem is that I got undefined and can not binding the events from uibmodal like like close dismiss or pass parameters to return to the uibmodal.result.then()

there is an example how to do that ?

Comment: not working from onInit also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `bindings`, not `binding`.

`$uibmodal` [supports these bindings](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs), so this is expected to work:

```
const TestModalComponent = {
    bindings:{
        resolve: '<',
        close: '&',
        dismiss: '&'
    },
    template: TestModalTemplate,
    controller: TestModalController
};
```

As it was noted in another answer, bindings are expected to appear not in constructor but in `$onInit` hook, this is what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method:

```
class TestModalController{
    constructor(){
        //NOT HERE
        //console.log(this.resolve) // got undefined
        //console.log(this.close) // got undefined
        //console.log(this.dismiss) // got undefined
    }

    $onInit(){
        //DO IT HERE
        console.log(this.resolve) 
        console.log(this.close) 
        console.log(this.dismiss) 

    }
}
```

From the Docs:

> ### `bindToController`
>
> After the controller is instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings will be bound to the controller properties. You can access these bindings once they have been initialized by providing a controller method called `$onInit`, which is called after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - `bindToController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-)

Comment: this is not working also from $onInit()